# How to UPDATE a table based on descending order of SALARY or SNO?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Suppose **Sal** of **emp** table is not in sequence order, I have to update a table in descending order based on **SAL**.

From my basics, It is possible to create a new table based on descending order from predefined table as shown code below.

***SQL>create table emp123 as select * from emp order by sal desc;***

My question is, I want to update a table directly into a database instead of creating a new table.

***Example:***: Change from 1st table to 2nd table
SQL> SELECT * FROM SECOND;

```
   ENO ENAME             SAL       COMM     MONSAL     ANNSAL
```

---

```
     2 MK               2000                  2000      24000
     1 SK               3000        200       3200      38400
     5 AK               1000        100       1100      13200
     3 BK               4000         20       4020      48240
     4 FK               1000        500       1500      18000
```

SQL> SELECT * FROM SECOND ORDER BY ENO;

```
   ENO ENAME             SAL       COMM     MONSAL     ANNSAL
```

---

```
     1 SK               3000        200       3200      38400
     2 MK               2000                  2000      24000
     3 BK               4000         20       4020      48240
     4 FK               1000        500       1500      18000
     5 AK               1000        100       1100      13200
```

Comment: How are you updating the table?  If you need to process it in a certain order, you can specify `order by` in the query used to fetch the data.

Comment: better to post some sample data and output what you want

Comment: Yes, I updated question

Answer (score 0):

Tables have no defined order.

It is the application's duty to do things in a certain sequence if it wants it so.

Comment: Of course, But I have to use in JAVA project as in serial order.